# Trouble determining slice indices for NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a NumPy array of `X * Y` elements, represented as a flatted array (`arr = np.array(x * y)`).

Given the following values:

```
X = 832
Y = 961
```

I need to access elements of the array in the following sequence:

```
arr[0:832:2]
arr[1:832:2]
arr[832:1664:2]
arr[833:1664:2]
...
arr[((Y-1) * X):(X * Y):2]
```

I'm not sure, mathematically, how to achieve the `start` and `stop` for each iteration in a loop.

Comment: This is an x-y problem. You almost *never* need to loop through a numpy array directly. If you show what you are trying to do with each chunk, I can improve my answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not looping the array, I'm looping a set of X and Y values and inserting values at the given `[start:stop:step]`, such as `arr[1:832:2] = 4`.

Comment: Can you show what you are actually doing? I still think this is an x-y problem because your goal is to access the elements of the array. For what purpose?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Script is on an entirely different machine (separated networks) so I can't copy and paste, would rather not introduce typos. That said, `arr` is a structured array representing a hexagon tessellation. `arr` has a shape of `(X * Y, )` and each element has a shape of `(7, 2)`. I'm iterating over the `Y` (column) range to assign values to the tessellation since each column shares x-axis values.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
This should do the trick

Y = 961
X = 832

all_ = np.random.rand(832*961)

# Iterating over the values of y
for i in range(1,Y):
    # getting the indicies from the array we need
    # i - 1 = Start
    # X*i = END
    # 2 is the step
    indicies = list(range(i-1,X*i,2))
    # np.take slice values from the array or get values corresponding to the list of indicies we prepared above
    required_array = np.take(indices=indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

To anybody interested in this solution (per iteration, not incrementing the shift each iteration):

```
for i in range(Y):
    shift = X * (i // 2)
    begin = (i % 2) + shift
    end = X + shift
    print(f'{begin}:{end}:2')
```

Comment: Use `Y*2` in the for loop. When you use `Y` it only runs till `399360`

Comment: @RamHarnish Why? I should only need to iterate over `Y`.

Comment: According to your question, the last term should be `(Y-1) * X), (X * Y):2` which is `798720: 799552` but your loop ends with `399360:400192:2`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array of shape `(x * y,)` that you want to process in chunks of `x`. You can simply reshape your array to shape `(y, x)` and process the rows:

```
>>> x = 832
>>> y = 961
>>> arr = np.arange(x * y)
```

Now reshape, and process in bulk. In the following example, I take the mean of each row. You can apply whatever functions you want to the entire array this way:

```
>>> arr = arr.reshape(y, x)
>>> np.mean(arr[:, ::2], axis=1)
>>> np.mean(arr[:, 1::2], axis=1)
```

The reshape operation does not alter the data in your array. The buffer it points to is the same as the original. You can invert the reshape by calling `ravel` on the array.